# How can i count the number of individual dates "mytable"

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> DESCRIBE mytable;
+-----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(255)          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| date      | timestamp         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  8 | 2014-01-23 23:59:37 |
|  9 | 2014-01-23 00:00:12 |
| 10 | 2014-01-24 00:00:22 |
| 11 | 2014-01-24 00:00:23 |
| 12 | 2014-01-24 00:00:24 |
| 13 | 2014-01-25 00:00:24 |
| 14 | 2014-01-25 00:00:29 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Table i need:

```
+-------+------------+
| Count | date       |
+-------+------------+
|  2    | 2014-01-23 |
|  3    | 2014-01-24 |
|  2    | 2014-01-24 |
+-------+------------+
```

because there are:

two records on date 2014-01-23

threerecords on date 2014-01-24

two records on date 2014-01-25

My incomplete solution:

SELECT COUNT(id) AS count, date FROM record_table WHERE ...;

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY DATE(date)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY` to group by dates:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS 'date', COUNT(id) AS 'count'
FROM record_table
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```